# Spark SQL: converting a week day name to an integer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert a day-of-the-week string name (e.g. TUESDAY) to an integer (e.g. 3). I wrote a Map below but I am not sure how to apply it.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lower

val dayNameToInteger = Map(
    "sunday"    -> 1,
    "monday"    -> 2,
    "tuesday"   -> 3,
    "wednesday" -> 4,
    "thursday"  -> 5,
    "friday"    -> 6,
    "saturday"  -> 7)


var input = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
    (0L, "SUNDAY", 34),
    (1L, "Monday", 31),
    (2L, "tuesday", 25)
    )).toDF("id", "day_of_week", "value")


scala> input.show
+---+-----------+-----+
| id|day_of_week|value|
+---+-----------+-----+
|  0|     SUNDAY|   34|
|  1|     Monday|   31|
|  2|    tuesday|   25|
+---+-----------+-----+


var output = input.select($"id", dayNameToInteger(lower(input("day_of_week"))))
<console>:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: String
       var output = input.select($"id", dayNameToInteger(lower(input("day_of_week"))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion should be done through a [UDF](http://www.sparktutorials.net/using-sparksql-udfs-to-create-date-times-in-spark-1.5), as that can operate on a column over all the rows.

```
val dayToInt = udf((dayOfWeek:String) => {
    dayOfWeek match {
        case "sunday"    => 1
        case "monday"    => 2
        case "tuesday"   => 3 
        case "wednesday" => 4
        case "thursday"  => 5
        case "friday"    => 6
        case "saturday"  => 7
    }
})  


var output = input.select($"id", dayToInt(lower(input("day_of_week"))).as("day_int"))


scala> output.show
+---+-------+
| id|day_int|
+---+-------+
|  0|      1|
|  1|      2|
|  2|      3|
+---+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement to the above answer, here is my Spark 2.x compatible take on the udf to index the day of week string to an integer:

```
spark.sqlContext.udf.register("dayToInt", (dayOfWeek:String) => {
    dayOfWeek.toLowerCase() match {
        case "sunday"    => 1
        case "monday"    => 2
        case "tuesday"   => 3 
        case "wednesday" => 4
        case "thursday"  => 5
        case "friday"    => 6
        case "saturday"  => 7
    }
})
```

Also usage for a machine learning model:

```
sql("""SELECT CAST(dayToInt(date_format(dateEst, 'EEEE')) AS float) AS dayOfWeekInt 
FROM data""")
```